# Battery "connected but not charging" after temperature spike

Tags: laptop, battery, temperature

My laptop (Avell B155 Fire V3) was accidentally transported while turned on. After noticing it was still on in the backpack it was immediately powered off (it was working "normally" from the battery at the time). About 20 minutes later when turned on again the battery icon was empty and it shows the massage "connected, not charging".

I don't think the battery is dead because it was working normally before turning it off. What might be the problem?

A few observations:

1) Battery led indicator are working properly.

2) sometimes it changes to "Connected, charging" but it never actually goes above 0%

3) Already tried resetting the bios and reinstalling the ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery driver.

Answer (score 0):

If you've left it on charge but not running for a day or two, and there was no improvement, then try resetting battery charging.

First check the [Avell manual](http://blog.avell.com.br/servicos/drivers/) for instructions. If there are none, the [general procedure for resetting charging](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-reset-a-laptop-battery) is:

- Uninstall the battery software from Device Manager (again). This was necessary on an HP laptop, but might not be on yours.
- Unplug the charger.
- Disconnect the battery or find the battery reset pinhole and insert a pin in it.
- Hold the power button for about 30 seconds.
- Plug in the power supply (and battery if removed) and restart the laptop.
- Open Device Manager (if Windows OS) and let it find and reinstall latest power management software.

On the aforementioned HP, I needed to repeat the process once before it corrected the "connected but not charging" issue.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In a similar setting, I'd run my laptop (ACER, Timeline X) near a heating ---> next day, when restarted, same observation occured.

Nothing obvious (remove battery, wait and reinsert,...) helped. Brought the laptop to the "laptop-clinic". Analysis: Inserting new battery does not help, USV-module defect.

***So, this information about "USV-module defect" might be another reason for the fail, and has not been mentioned so far.***

Hmm, never heard of an "USV"-module in a notebook. But might be possible. I can only work with laptop on AC since...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).