# Xiaomi Notebook Pro GTX does not turn on without a charger

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, charger

Good afternoon. 
Bought a laptop at the beginning of the year and faced a problem: the laptop does not turn on without a connected charger. I press the ON button and see the LED blinking red. If the power button is pressed > 5 sec the LED flashes red at ~1Hz and then ~2Hz and goes out. 
If the charger is connected at startup, the notebook will start up and you can pull out the charger immediately - it will run quietly for about 6 hours from the battery, i.e. the battery seems to be in order.
BIOS is updated. .
Tell me, fellow connoisseurs, what may be the problem? Where to dig?

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the battery. For Windows (it is helpful to state the OS), this involves uninstalling ACPI battery drivers, removing the battery, unplugging the power supply, draining any remaining charge and reversing those steps.

On SuperUser, see [Battery “connected but not charging”](https://superuser.com/questions/1294116/battery-connected-but-not-charging-after-temperature-spike) or [Battery not charging, laptop only works when plugged](https://superuser.com/questions/1305783/battery-not-charging-laptop-only-works-when-plugged) for specific details.

Comment: Thank you for advise but I've done that previously and it didn't help unfortunately.