# No "Firmware" category in Device Manager?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, bios, battery

Using Windows 10 on a hp 255 g5. A few months after getting it (1.5 years ago) - a big problem started one day. My laptop can not function for more than 2 or 3 minutes without being plugged in to a power source - or it shuts down. As I've been home almost the entire year it hasn't been much of a problem but it is now. Before jumping to buy a $150 replacement battery, I googled my issue in hope of finding a solution. I've found numerous options but non seem to currently work.

(Btw, this is a big big issue itself but I'm still going to cover some more solutions. This isn't the subject of this post though. If none work I'll post here again. If someone has an idea for a fix for this I'll be glad to know.)

One of the solutions I'm trying out right now are updating my BIOS. Is that even a good idea? One website says it can corrupt my pc. Anyways, to update the BIOS, I'm supposed to go to the `device manager` and then to `firmware`, then enter my driver. Problem is  - **there's no firmware category!**

[image]

Comment: There's no problem with updating your BIOS - as long as it's from your manufacturer's website and you don't do things like disconnect the power, etc. After that, maybe try pressing the 'scan for hardware changes' button? Sometimes my PC glitches with different peripherals I have and they disappear from device manager, but that fixes it.

Comment: The last time I updated a BIOS, I had to download and run a program which caused a flash process to kick off on next reboot (Dell).  I didn't have to look for a device but it was a long time ago.  Please provide a link to the instructions you are referencing.  FWIW it's possible the "Other devices" has this firmware device but it's not showing because a correct driver isn't installed.

Comment: First of all, it isn't a BIOS.. even if that is what the manufacturer calls it.  BIOS firmware hasn't existed for many years now.  What you are talking about is *UEFI Firmware*.  Even in LEGACY MODE, it is still good 'ol UEFI.  Second of all, there isn't a driver from windows point of view.  It is what BOOTS WINDOWS so how could windows have a driver for it?  Makes no sense.  If there is a driver.. it isn't for your firmware, it is for windows to be able to COMMUNICATE with your firmware (and dont need it).  See @LawrenceC comment .. UEFI update is outside of windows.

Comment: Oh I know all the differences between BIOS and UEFI.  Many people and even PC manufacturer websites still (wrongly) call it BIOS even though it's been all UEFI for many years now.  Historically flash update utilities that update your system firmware haven't needed a "Firmware" device in Device Manager to do an update (I remember updating BIOSes on WinXP, Win7, etc.).  It might be different lately.  Some Windows 10 systems for whatever reason do have firmware devices there (I found more than a couple pictures with a Google search on "Windows 10 Firmware Device").  Maybe a driver is needed.

Comment: First, try to reset battery charging: https://superuser.com/questions/1294116/battery-connected-but-not-charging-after-temperature-spike . Second, you might find a third-party battery for **much** less, online. Buy from a reputable store, should there be an issue, but I've have not had a problem using third-party batteries.